# Wit AI speech recognition

Tags: python, wit.ai

I am trying to submit an audio in ogg format to https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20200513. I need to receive a text representation of the voice. When I submit the code through curl request, it returns empty response as `{"_text": "", "entities": ""}`. I also tried to execute it with pywit. Below is the code:

```
from wit import Wit

client = Wit('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
with open('2.ogg', 'rb') as f:
    print(f)
    resp = client.post_speech(f, content_type='audio/ogg')

print('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + str(resp))
```

My guess was that the file is not captured, but print shows `_io.BufferedReader name='2.ogg'`, which means that the file is stored in the buffer, but wit ai refuses to transcribe it.

Why does wit respond with empty `_text`?

Comment: This does not seem like a programming question.

Comment: I’m asking about the API-related problem, and how it functions, I explained what i tried and what were my guesses. Why is that not a programming question?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, even with wav files. Most of the time it works, but sometimes it just keep returning empty _text and entities..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but the problem happens only with OGG files even though documentation states that it does work with this file extension. So, I had to convert the audio into WAV and try again. This time it worked perfectly well.